# How to change the primeng calendar height?

Tags: angular, primeng

how to change height of primeng calendar not input field.

[image]

Update 1:

After applying below styles, calendar appear as below

```
.ui-calendar .ui-datepicker {
height : 200px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all this solutions it's not working for me
so basically we need to reduce the padding between the td element of date picker
try to override/use below class.

```
 //first try below
**body .p-datepicker table td {
    padding: 0.13rem; // use as per your requirement.
  }** 

 //if not working above then use with ng:deep

 **::ng-deep .p-datepicker table td {
            padding: 0.13rem; // use as per your requirement.
          }**
```

**Note: These classes working after primeng version >=10 because previous they are using  ui-datepicker class.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa2cD.jpg)  in primeng v10 now they using p-datepicker prefix p- instead of ui**

[see below images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbPZd.jpg)

Comment: Thank you, the 2nd option using `::ng-deep` worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite below class of prime ng calendar

```
.ui-calendar .ui-datepicker {
height : 200px;
}
```

Add below css also:

```
.ui-datepicker td span, .ui-datepicker td a {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, setting above style made calendar inconsistent .Dates are moving out of calendar.

Comment: I have just given example to alter css of calendar..you have to manage other css attribute accordingly html structure...please share screenshot and css your have added. i may help you

Comment: Updated question with screenshot

Comment: Updated my answer for your issue..Please check

Answer (score 1):

This css is work for me:

```
::ng-deep .p-datepicker table td {
  padding: 0.2rem !important;
}

::ng-deep .p-datepicker table td > span {
  width: 1.7rem;
  height: 1.7rem;
}

::ng-deep .p-datepicker table {
  font-size: 10pt;
  margin: -0.143rem 0;
}

::ng-deep .p-datepicker .p-datepicker-header {
  padding: 0.2rem;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use [style] or [styleClass]

```
<p-calendar [styleClass]="'custom-height'"></p-calendar>
```

In your css use below:

```
.custom-height:{height:300px}
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find any solution so what I did to reduce the height of calender

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="ui-float-label">
    <p-calendar showTime="true" hourFormat="12" [(ngModel)]="value" inputId="text" id="text" [showIcon]="true" [inline]="true"></p-calendar>
    <label id="inline-lable" for="text" class="ml-2">{{label}}</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container ::ng-deep p-calendar .ui-datepicker table td {
  padding: 1px !important;
}
.container ::ng-deep p-calendar .ui-datepicker .ui-timepicker {
  padding: 2px 0 0 0 !important;
}
.container ::ng-deep p-calendar .ui-datepicker {
  padding: 0.857em 0.857em 0 0.857em !important;
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Override primeng calender-widget height CSS:

```
 ::ng-deep .ui-datepicker.ui-widget{
    line-height: 0.5rem;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using PrimeNG v10.

On a per a single control for the date-picker you can use ***panelStyle***:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]='addTime.StartTime' [panelStyle]="{'height':'280px'}"></p-calendar>
```

Or use panelStyleClass, documentation say:

> ***panelStyleClass***   string    null    Style class of the datetimepicker  container element.
>
> ***panelStyle***   object null    Inline style of the datetimepicker container element.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in you global stylesheet with !important behind like this:

```
.ui-calendar .ui-datepicker {
height : 200px !important;
}
```

But maybe you are annoyed by the fact your datepicker is hidden behind your button.
If so, simply add appendTo="body" in your p-calendar element, like this:

```
<p-calendar appendTo="body" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></p-calendar>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works for me

```
:host >>> .p-datepicker table td > span {
    height: unset;
    width: unset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to set **display** to **initial** on .p-datepicker td>span, like this:

```
.p-datepicker td>span {
    display: initial;
  }
```

Then you change the font-size as you which so it changes the width.